# How can I avoid repeating code initializing a hashmap of hashmap?

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap

Every client has an id, and many invoices, with dates, stored as Hashmap of clients by id, of a hashmap of invoices by date:

```
HashMap<LocalDateTime, Invoice> allInvoices = allInvoicesAllClients.get(id);

if(allInvoices!=null){
    allInvoices.put(date, invoice);      //<---REPEATED CODE
}else{
    allInvoices = new HashMap<>();
    allInvoices.put(date, invoice);      //<---REPEATED CODE
    allInvoicesAllClients.put(id, allInvoices);
}
```

Java solution seems to be to use `getOrDefault`:

```
HashMap<LocalDateTime, Invoice> allInvoices = allInvoicesAllClients.getOrDefault(
    id,
    new HashMap<LocalDateTime, Invoice> (){{  put(date, invoice); }}
);
```

But if get is not null, I still want put (date, invoice) to execute, and also adding data to "allInvoicesAllClients" is still needed. So it doesn't seem to help much.

Comment: If you can't guarantee the uniqueness of the key, you're best bet is to have the secondary map have value of List<Invoice> instead of just Invoice.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is an excellent use-case for [`Map#computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)). Your snippet is essentially equivalent to:

```
allInvoicesAllClients.computeIfAbsent(id, key -> new HashMap<>()).put(date, invoice);
```

If `id` isn't present as a key in `allInvoicesAllClients`, then it'll create mapping from `id` to a new `HashMap` and return the new `HashMap`. If `id` is present as a key, then it'll return the existing `HashMap`.

Comment: computeIfAbsent, does a get (id) (or a put folllowed by a get (id) ), so next put is done to correct item put(date), right answer.

Comment: `allInvoicesAllClients.computeIfAbsent(id, key -> Map.of(date, invoice))`

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica `Map.of` creates an unmodifiable `Map`, which I'm not sure the OP wants.

Comment: Would this code be less efficient than what the OP had originally? Asking this because I'm not familiar with how Java handles lambda functions.

Answer (score 16):

`computeIfAbsent` is a great solution for this particular case. In general, I'd like to note the following, since nobody mentioned it yet:

The "outer" hashmap just stores a *reference* to the "inner" hashmap, so you can just reorder the operations to avoid the code duplication:

```
HashMap<LocalDateTime, Invoice> allInvoices = allInvoicesAllClients.get(id);

if (allInvoices == null) {           
    allInvoices = new HashMap<>();
    allInvoicesAllClients.put(id, allInvoices);
}

allInvoices.put(date, invoice);      // <--- no longer repeated
```

Comment: This is how we did this for decades before Java 8 came along with its fancy `computeIfAbsent()` method!

Comment: I still use this approach today in languages where the map implementation does not provide a single get-or-put-and-return-if-absent method. That this can still be the best solution in other languages may be worth mentioning even though this question is specifically tagged for Java 8.

Answer (score 11):

You should pretty much never use "double brace" map initialization.

```
{{  put(date, invoice); }}
```

In this case, you should use `computeIfAbsent`

```
allInvoicesAllClients.computeIfAbsent(id, (k) -> new HashMap<>())
                     .put(date, allInvoices);
```

If there is no map for this ID, you will insert one. The result will be the existing or computed map. You can then `put` items in that map with guarantee that it won't be null.

Comment: I don't know who downvote, not me, perhaps single line code is confusing allInvoicesAllClients put, because you use id instead of date, I'll edit it

Comment: @HernánEche Ah. My mistake. Thanks. Yes the put for `id` is done as well. You can think of `computeIfAbsent` as a conditional put if you like. And it returns the value as well

Comment: "*You should pretty much never use "double brace" map initialization.*" Why? (I don't doubt that you are right; I am asking out of genuine curiosity.)

Comment: @Heinzi Because it creates an anonymous inner class. This holds a reference to the class which declared it, which if you expose the map (e.g. via a getter) will prevent the enclosing class from being garbage collected. Also, I find it can be confusing for people less familiar with Java; initializer blocks are hardly ever used, and writing it like this makes it look like `{{ }}` has special meaning, which it doesn't.

Comment: @Michael: Makes sense, thanks. I totally forgot that anonymous inner classes are always non-static (even if they don't need to be).

Answer (score 5):

This is longer than the other answers, but imho far more readable:

```
if(!allInvoicesAllClients.containsKey(id))
    allInvoicesAllClients.put(id, new HashMap<LocalDateTime, Invoice>());

allInvoicesAllClients.get(id).put(date, invoice);
```

Comment: This may work for a HashMap but the general approach is not optimal. If these were ConcurrentHashMaps, these operations are not atomic. In such case, check-then-act will lead to race conditions. Upvoted anyway, f the haters.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing two separate things here: ensuring that the `HashMap` exists, and adding the new entry to it.

The existing code makes sure to insert the new element first before registering the hash map, but that isn't necessary, because the `HashMap` doesn't care about the ordering here. Neither variant is threadsafe, so you're not losing anything.

So, like @Heinzi suggested, you can just split these two steps.

What I would also do is offload the creation of the `HashMap` to the `allInvoicesAllClients` object, so the `get` method cannot return `null`.

This also reduces the possibility for races between separate threads that could both get `null` pointers from `get` and then decide to `put` a new `HashMap` with a single entry -- the second `put` would probably discard the first, losing the `Invoice` object.